# Java Mission Control in the JDK: What can it be used for for free?

Tags: java, oracle, jmc

Java Mission Control has been included with the Oracle JDK since Java 7u40.

It is very clear from the JMC documentation that this is a commercial feature, but the JDK documentation does not clearly indicate when you can use JMC for free, and when you need an Java SE Advanced license.  This could be because Oracle want this to be used and therefore has made it freely available, or because they do the usual "free for development, pay for production" policy and just want to lure developers into using new expensive toys.

Anyone who has found the precise terms?

---

EDIT:  As of Java 11, jfc is part of the open source OpenJDK  and not only the Oracle supported Oracle Java 11. See [Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later).

Comment: For those wanting to close:  JMC is a profiling tool included with the Java _DEVELOPMENT_ Kit.  It does not come more programming related than that.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMEpRUgp9Y4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The terms of the Oracle Binary License *specifically* and *defnitively* deal with this.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html.  See the Supplemental Terms section, section A.

Comment: @StephenC it does (I believe it says JMC is "free for development, pay for _any_ kind of production") but somehow I get the feeling that this could have been put in clearer language in a more visible location when Oracle adds new trialware functionality to a software package traditionally known to be "completely free to use (but you cannot redistribute it)".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - That's why you should always read the license before you click to agree :-)

Comment: I agree that this is certainly a programming related question and is not off-topic